# Python как вовремя написания кода интерфейса, сразу видеть результат работы

Tags: python, вёрстка, flet

Коллеги, нашел видео в котором при написании кода python с библиотекой  flet программист в режиме реального времени видит изменение страницы которую он пишет, то есть кнопки и элементы верстки появляются сразу вовремя написания строк кода.Пример котором это происходит по ссылке   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPG5tpWgxy0. Кто то знает как именно это делается, я пробовал гуглить, но не могу найти ответ на вопрос. Как эта технология называется.

Answer (score 0):

Это именно [Flet](https://github.com/flet-dev/flet) -- это фреймворк, со встроенным Web сервером (Flutter Web).

Comment: Он, когда в консоле пишет что то получается веб сервер запускает?

Comment: На видео запускает python скрипт в среде Flet, а результат работы отображается в нативном окне операционной системы  т.е. как самостоятельное приложение. Для отображения в броузере надо немного модифицировать код вызова:
```
 flet.app(target=main, view=flet.WEB_BROWSER)
```
см. [к примеру](https://habr.com/ru/articles/677734/)